# BizTalk Adapters

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm fairly new to BizTalk, at this point I'm just exploring its functionality and learning about how the different pieces (schemas, orchestrations, ports, etc) work together. I have a question about its adapters:

Are the different adapters already pre-installed with the BizTalk server installation and ready to configure or are some of them, like the JD Edwards one, on a separate installation and work more like a plug in?

I'm still trying to wrap my head around BizTalk so please correct me if I've got the view all wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapters like File, FTP, WCF, MSMQ, HTTP, SMTP, POP3 are the ones which come out of the box with BizTalk Server Installation and you just start using them.

But some of the enterprise adapters like JDE, PeopleSoft, Oracle, SAP, Tibco etc you need to install the BizTalk Enterprise Adapter pack and then configure them.

More Info:

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/adapter-pack.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/adapters-included.aspx

Comment: Also, when you work with the adapters for other applications, like Siebel or SAP, you will need to install their client tools on the BizTalk server.  Those adapters typically wrap the client API in a big WCF Service with messages for each of the functions.